# Android - How to scale text without dithering/antialiasing - I want the pixelated text

Tags: android, text, 2d, android-canvas

For an experiment I want to draw pixelated text on a canvas.

This is what I have so far:

```
Paint text = new Paint();
text.setAntiAlias(false);
text.setFilterBitmap(false);
text.setDither(false);
text.setFakeBoldText(false);
text.setLinearText(false);
text.setTextSize(10);

// Scale the canvas we draw on
matrix = c.getMatrix();
matrix.reset();
matrix.postTranslate(0, 0);
matrix.postScale(10,10);
c.setMatrix(matrix);
c.drawText("ABCabc", 0, 10, text);
```

This achieves the size I want, but the text is antialiased and dithered, and this is not what I want.

The closest I've gotten is by doing this:

```
    text.setTextScaleX(5);
```

which scales the text the way I want horizontally, but unfortunately there is no text.setTextScaleY-functuion...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use text.setTextSize(n) and scale up the font instead?

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is a really old question but here's a simple solution if anyone's still looking for one:

```
textView.setTextScaleX(scaleX);
textView.setScaleY(scaleY);
```

So by letting `scaleX == scaleY`, the font will be scaled uniformly as expected.